# windows phone 8.1 tracking user actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to get notified about what the user presses outside of my applicayion screen, while it runs in the background?
 I dont need the ability to change his choices or something like that, only get notified about them.
 For example if he cencelled a call I want to note that in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not possible. You can use background tasks to subscribe to certian events that occur when the user interacts with the system:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx